# Not entering loop even though it should

Tags: javascript

I am having loop issues in javascript.
I've come across a strange issue all of a sudden where for certain values my loop doesn't trigger, even though it seems it should.

```
var j = holiday_starts;

console.log(j);
console.log(holiday_ends);

if (j<=holiday_ends){
    console.log("TRUE");
}
```

Where in this case, `holiday_starts` is 6 and `holiday_ends` is 10 (checked with the console log). This is NOT logging TRUE. It only happens for some cases not others.

If I set the variables directly (`j = 6, holiday_ends = 10`) then it will log TRUE.

What have I missed? Is this due to something else in my code somewhere?

Comment: Check the datatypes

Comment: You should probably be aware that the *string* "6" may not be less than "10", if it uses lexicographical ordering.

Comment: then as suggested check the datatype. or try using `parseInt(holiday_ends)` same for start also or `Number(holiday_ends)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are getting holiday_starts and holiday_ends as *string* (probably from an user input?). When that happen, the comparition is made as string, and 6 is after 1 in the alphabet, "6" < "10" is false, like in this snippet:

```js
var holiday_starts = "6";
var holiday_ends = "10";
var j = holiday_starts;

console.log(j);
console.log(holiday_ends);

if (j<=holiday_ends){
    console.log("TRUE");
}
```

In that case, you should `parseInt` the input before comparing, the below snippet works as intended:

```js
var holiday_starts = parseInt("6");
var holiday_ends = parseInt("10");
var j = holiday_starts;

console.log(j);
console.log(holiday_ends);

if (j <= holiday_ends) {
  console.log("TRUE");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing strings not integers. So just convert to integer types before comparing.

Like this:

```
if (Number(j)<=Number(holiday_ends)){
    console.log("TRUE");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

They are being compared alphabetically because its assumed they are String.

Convert them explicitly to Number using `Number()` or `parsInt()`. Then you'll get right answer

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that one of the variables holds a string value.

Check this via `typeof` keyword:

```
var j = holiday_starts;

console.log(j);
console.log(holiday_ends);

if (j<=holiday_ends){
    console.log("TRUE");
}
else {
    console.log("Type of j:" + (typeof j) + " // Type of holiday_ends:" + (typeof holiday_ends));
}
```

And fix accordingly